# Higher or Lower guessing game structuring problem, i had to look up the solution but it still makes no sense to me

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

im doing the 100 days of Python by Angela Yu and i just finished off day 14 today, the higher or lower follower count guessing game... I tried doing it all myself but i ended up getting lost when i needed to recycle the previous winning answer with the 1st option in the second round.. I Tried many things but none of them worked... so i looked at the answer and this makes absolutely no sense to me at all.

```
def game():
  print(logo)
  score = 0
  game_should_continue = True
  account_a = get_random_account()
  account_b = get_random_account()

  while game_should_continue:
    account_a = account_b
    account_b = get_random_account()

    while account_a == account_b:
      account_b = get_random_account()

    print(f"Compare A: {format_data(account_a)}.")
    print(vs)
    print(f"Against B: {format_data(account_b)}.")
    
    guess = input("Who has more followers? Type 'A' or 'B': ").lower()
    a_follower_count = account_a["follower_count"]
    b_follower_count = account_b["follower_count"]
    is_correct = check_answer(guess, a_follower_count, b_follower_count)

    clear()
    print(logo)
    if is_correct:
      score += 1
      print(f"You're right! Current score: {score}.")
    else:
      game_should_continue = False
      print(f"Sorry, that's wrong. Final score: {score}")
```

The get random account function fetches an dictionary from a list containing name follower count etc..
The function is ran twice to provide 2 variable entries A and B, these 2 are then printed in console and the input you enter gives back a result, i did all this myself quite successfully... Where i am really not understanding the logic is; once you get it right and the game reruns, how does

```
while game_should_continue:
    account_a = account_b
    account_b = get_random_account()
```

account_a = account_b "Fetch" the value of the previous account_b ? surely it should just rerun the get_random_account() by doing that?

The reason i'm going through all this trouble to ask this after finishing is because i was convinced it could be done by inserting some return statements if game was won and simply reusing them as a parameter in the game() function.. but i didn't manage to get this to work.... Is it even possible?

Comment: `a` is what `b` was previously and `b` is a new random one - what is the confusion here?

Comment: Im still quite new to all this so my logic may not be the best, i thought it was impossible to get a value from a function without calling it, therefore doesnt account_a = account_b invoke the function again?

Comment: No, that does not invoke a function, that assigns the value from b to a. You should probably follow more (python) tutorials, they should cover what variables are, what functions are, what return values are, how they work and interact, etc.